# how to log service topic messages in azure?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I found a way to query the AzureActivity Log in Azure to get a result set of changes that were made to Service Bus Topics like add, rename, delete.  The result of changes includes info like TimeGenerated, HttpRequest, ResourceId. But this result set of changes is only for structural changes.

I'd like to configure my Azure instance to log the actual messages that are added to the topic, not just structural changes to a topic definition.  The result set should include the same fields of TimeGenerated, HttpRequest, ResourceId.  I'm guessing that there's a way to configure Azure to do this but I'm not sure how this would be done.  Can you advise how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can query the Activity logs specific to message processing.

All the management operations like create, edit, delete are possible in Azure portal, so they are capturing those events and allow us to query them.

There is no support for any kind of message processing in Azure portal and it is possible only through APIs and Libraries. So, they cannot track something which happened outside the portal.